# Django re-usable form csrf error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, csrf, django-csrf

I'd like to add a form to log a user at more than one page on my website using Django.  Instead of having to replicate the form multiple times, I want to use an "include" statement to import the same form.  My code right now  does two things incorrectly:  it does not show a field to enter a username or password, and submiting the form produces a CSRF 403 (Forbidden) error.

sample html:

```
        <!-- Login -->
<div id="login">
    <form action="/login/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include "registration/login_snippet.html" %}
            <p>
            <input type="submit" value="login"/></p>
            </form>
</div>
```

login_snippet.html:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="id_username">
    Username:
</label>
{% if form.username.errors %} 
<span class="error">
{{ form.username.errors|join:", " }}
</span>
{% endif %}
{{ form.username }}
<label for="id_password">
     Password:
</label>
{% if form.password.errors %} 
<span class="error">
    {{ form.password.errors|join:", " }}
</span>
{% endif %}
{{ form.password }}
```

Here is what's being displayed:
[image: login form]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding the following to your code. I am not 100% sure, but I think it should work. Obviously, this disables the csrf protection. However, it should allow you to continue to run your website. While csrf is important, I am not sure that it is mandatory on every single view.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    #Make this a function in your classview

        @csrf_exempt
        def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return super(YOUR_VIEW_NAME_HERE, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

**For problem 1 (no field for username and password):**

Are you sure the form object is in the context? It seems like there is no {{ form }} that the template has access to, so it can't render {{ form.username }}

**For Problem 2 (csrf):**

You are including the {% csrf_token %} twice. Once in sample.html and once in login_snippet.html. Removing one of them might solve the issue.

**Finally,**

Also, is there any reason why the entire login form is not in one snippet? Why separate the 'form' element from the fields?